# How to adjust the background according to the text length

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the background behind text according to the text i write towards right.
For example if the Text in place of "Title" would be "He is out today" Then the background should highlight till "today"i.e according to the length of text.
If i write more big sentence then the background should stretch towards right according to the sentence.

```css
.container-text {
      text-align: left;
      background-color: #F1F1F1;
    .text {
          font-family: "Sans"
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-text">
<div class="text">Title</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `text` class outside of the `.container-text` in your css file and then use `display: inline-block;` to stretch the width of the `div` to its content only:

```css
.container-text {
  text-align: left;
}
.text {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  font-family: "Sans";
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-text">
  <div class="text">Title<div>
<div>
```

Comment: I dont want to add an extra background-color, The one which I have used on the div `container-text` want to be adjusted, I have edited my question because it makes a confusion with the reverse thing

Comment: I dont want `background-color: red` All I want is that gray highlight to be adjusted according to the sentence

Comment: @Aditya check now

Comment: yes great, it is good but I want this background slightly more in length as compared to text, and when I replace the text with long sentence it also changes.can it be possible?And please upvote the question if it is okay

Answer (score 0):

1. your code is wrong. your tags don't close...
2. your classes are wrong - look at the names
3. this should be correct:

```css
.text {
        display:inline-block;
        
        background-color: #F1F1F1;
         font-family: "Sans"
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-text">
  <div class="text">Title Title Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes you are correct may be by mistake it was a typo.. let me edit this.

Comment: I have edited my question and removed the rever-text container part, And also I dont want to add the extra color background, the background color I have added in the `container-text` class need to be used

Comment: ok...but now your question and the code don't fit since your question still contains the part about the text that is _reverse_. i left it in my answer

Comment: if you dont want a different background color at all...what is your question then? you can't highlight the text without setting a different background-color...

Comment: can you see the gray background-color behind the text ?

Comment: you said you want the text (not only reverse, all?) to have the same color as given in the container, but only to the text length? then put the color to the text and not to the container. 

sorry, but still you are not specific in what you want and you code still is wrong (no closing-tags!). it's very hard to help in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you can use pseudo code to achieve this.

```css
.container-text {
      text-align: left;
      width:100%;
      background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
.text {
      font-family: "Sans";
      position:relative;
      display:inline-block;
      z-index:3;
      color:#fff;
}
.text::before{position:absolute;content:"";background:#ff0000;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:-1;}
```

```html
    <div class="container-text">
    <div class="text">Title</div>
    </div>
```